Как поместить Django-форму в модальное окно Bootstrap?
Я использую стандартные django.contrib.auth.urls, чтобы отображать формы авторизации.
Проблема в том, что если использовать для этих целей модальные окна Bootstrap, то по какой-то причине форма поля ввода формы не передаются в шаблон и выглядит это вот так:

Шаблон модального окна:
# index.html
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
                {% include 'registration/login.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Шаблон формы:
# login.html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Войти">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
</form>

Код ссылки:
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Войти</a>

Если перейти по прямому адресу, но элементы формы есть:

Может быть они не загружаются, потому что при нажатии на ссылку не происходит непосредственного перехода по ней? Как это можно исправить?
Модалка:
<div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="logoutModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
                {% include 'registration/logged_out.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Шаблон logged_out.html:
<h4 class="mb-3">Вы вышли из системы</h4>
<p><a class="link-underline link-underline-opacity-0 link-opacity-50-hover" href="{% url 'login' %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Войти</a></p>

При нажатии на ссылку, модальное окно появляется, шаблон в нём корректный:

Но фактического выхода из аккаунта не происходит, если обновить страницу, пользователь останется авторизованным.
Мне кажется, что природа этой проблемы схожа с изначальной

Получается, при нажатии на ссылку, становится видно модальное окно, которое просто отображает html, в котором нет переменной form. Выглядит так, что нужно поля формы писать вручную, что не очень правильно

Ну, переменную form вам неизбежно придётся откуда-то добыть. На стандартной вьюхе входа её добавляет собственно сама стандартная вьюха, а на нестандартной вьюхе придётся изобретать её как-то самостоятельно

Собственно, стандартная вьюха использует AuthenticationForm

Я как раз использую стандартную форму
Как я представляю себе работу:
Я нажимаю на кнопку, появляется модальное окно, которое отрисовывает html с формой из файла login.html
Но вью вызывается только при переходе по ссылке (запрос на эндпоинт/accounts/login), но при нажатии на кнопку "Войти" непосредственного перехода по ссылке не происходит, поэтому вью не вызывается, соответственно и форма не отрисовывается

Ну вот я и говорю - вам нужно добыть form в том вью, которое отрисовывает это ваше модальное окно

Хотя если модальное окно отрисовывается во всех вью, то тогда это уже работа для context processors (и тогда уже лучше переименовать form во что-нибудь более внятное, чтобы не путать с другими формами сайта)

У меня используется стандартное вью из django.contrib.auth.urls, а именно LoginView

У меня одностраничник, который отрисовывает таблицу
Если пользователь не авторизован, то в шапке ссылка на вход
Если авторизован, то 2 ссылки, на смену пароля и на выход
Плюс ещё для каждой записи таблицы есть своя ссылка на редактирование этой записи
Каждая ссылка - модальное окно
Соответственно, все окна будут на одной странице

Ну тогда, опять же, вам нужно добыть form в том вью, которое отрисовывает этот ваш одностраничник

добавил в описание похожий кейс

А при выходе, разумеется, нужно отправлять какой-нибудь запрос на сервер, чтобы сервер хотя бы в принципе узнал, что пользователь пытается выйти

Нужно использовать что-то вроде ajax для этого?

Большое спасибо за помощь!
У меня получилось сделать так:

Понадобилось добавить небольшой запрос и встраивать полученный в ответе html-код в модальное окно:
$('#login').click(function () {
        let loginUrl = $(this).data('url');
        let csrfToken = $(this).data('csrf-token');

        $.ajax({
            url: loginUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#loginModal .modal-body').html(response);
            }
        });
    });

